# Need Improve Sequence Detection Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, math

This question is complex, so please ask questions for explaining more detail on this quesiton. (ps. Im not native English speaker, thats why...)

the input is that ***sample* sequence** with length of 34, while the output is the **result** part

For now, I have a sequence ***sample*** that is **length of 34**, it may be constructed as:
("result" is what I need)

The ***sample* sequence** = **result** part + **known sequence** (I didnt know the length of **result** part)

1. **result** (length 34)
2. **result** (length N, N < 34) + **known sequence** (34 - N)

All those numbers in sequence are random.

Right now, I need to find **result** part without including the **sequence known** part.

Some background info:

1. I have 10 millions this ***sample* sequence** with length of 34.
   (10 millions of knowing 34 digits random number sequence from generator)
2. After I find the result, I will need to make it to compare on a 5 million length of sequence *B*, and find if the result sequence is uniquely match on the long sequence somewhere.

My current algrothm is to use a **detector** which is first 10 digits of **known sequence**, and remove the sequence after if I detect detecter sequence somewhere in ***sample* sequence**. However, there is still a chance that **result** contains the part of sequence inside of the **known sequence**. Does anyone has a better algrothm?

Thanks so much! In addition, I'm programming this under python.

ex.

**1st condition**:

199010104761700150004736290473629657 == sample seq

all are result and known part still the same

input:

199010104761700150004736290473629657

output:

199010104761700150004736290473629657

**2nd condition**:

199010104728392817111123995561547659 == sample seq

1990101047 == result part

28392817111123995561547659... == known part

input will be: 199010104728392817111123995561547659, 28392817111123995561547659...

output I want is: 1990101047

Comment: sample input & sample output?

Comment: This really isn't clear.  Are you saying you have 10 million sample sequences with different "results", or 10 million sequences with the same "result" but different "known sequences", or 10 million sequences with different values of "N"?  Is the value of "N" known?  Part 2 sounds like a completely unrelated problem...

Comment: In summary, I agree that you should add some simple examples to your question, in order to illustrate what's going on here.

Comment: Please tell me where exactly is not clear, so I can improve the question. I'm sorry about all those. Thanks guys! I will go lunch back in an hour. Thanks for all!

Comment: I gave an example and it is my current view of the algrothm of this question. I want a better algrothm if possible.

Comment: @windsound: how about posting the code for your algorithm. That might help explain what you are doing better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). You won't actually find the substring, but you can take  note of the value of `i` when you reach the end of the subject string.

Comment: Thanks for answering anyway! That is actually very helpful, thanks a lot!